# Chosen dropdown is holding focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events, jquery-chosen

I have a dropdown list that implements the Chosen plugin.  When an option is selected, the cursor is supposed to be put in a textbox on the same page.  I'm trying to use the `onChange` attribute of the dropdown to accomplish this, but it isn't working.  The `onChange` event is being fired, but the focus stays on the dropdown.

When I disable Chosen, it works perfectly.  So I know it has something to do with the plugin, but I don't know what the exact problem is.

**Why is the Chosen dropdown preventing jQuery from switching the focus?**

The relevant HTML:

```
<!--Unrelated code has been removed--> 
<div class="mws-form-col-8-8 ">
    <div class="mws-form-item large">
    @Html.DropDownList("addOtherProvision" + chargeId, Model.otherProvisionDropdown, "",
                           new { onchange = "$('#additionalDetails').focus();", 
                                 id = "addOtherProvision" + chargeId })
    </div>
</div>

<div id= "@(chargeId)otherProvisionDialog" class="mws-panel-body"
    title="Add Additional Details">
    <div class="mws-form-cols clearfix">
        <div class="mws-form-item large">
            @Html.TextBox("additionalDetails", "", new {id = "additionalDetails", 
                           @class = "mws-textinput" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions in the console?

Comment: @HanletEscaño No, I am not getting any exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this has been an issue with the last couple of versions. These have been addressed [Here](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/2139) and mainly [Here](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/1526). The workaround simply adds a [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) that removes the selected class from the Chosen element, and waits a little bit (enough for the next loop to execute) and focuses then:

```
$("select").chosen().on('change', function(evt, params) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('chosen-container-active');
        $('#additionalDetails').focus();
    }, 0);
});
```

Given the nature of your markup (you are using Razor) I would suggest having this in your JavaScript instead to improve readability.

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/q22vy16j/